# How to use variable from previous function iteration in bash script

Tags: bash, function

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

r () {
        read -rp "Give text: " var
}

m () { 
        if [ -n "$2" ] ; then
                echo " && $1"
                g='1'
        else
                echo "$1"
                g=''
        fi
}

r
t1="$g"
a="$(m "$var" "")"

r
t2="$g"
b="$(m "$var" "$t1")"

r
c="$(m "$var" "$t2")"

echo "$a$b$c"
```

I want to run this script with a combination of the following input:
Enter "fire" or just hit enter to leave empty.
Enter "water" or just hit enter to leave empty.
Enter "air" or just hit enter to leave empty.
By that I mean just the words or nothing.

Currently when I run this, I get the following possible combinations:

```
firewaterair
firewater
waterair
fire
water
air
```

What I am trying to achieve is these possible outcomes:

```
fire && water && air
fire && water
water && air
fire 
water
air
```

I tried several things but not sure why this script does not work as intended. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `$( ... )` runs in a subshell environment. all changes are lost after it finishes, so setting `g` there has no effect

Comment: Don't use all single letter variables in your code but if you do then don't ask anyone else to have to try to understand it to help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single-letter variables obscures your code. I can understand that `r` probably stands for "read", but what's the purpose exactly of the function you simply called `m`? Giving it a useful name also helps yourself understand your code. But more fundamentally, a function should ideally not have any side effects outside of its own scope.

A better design altogether is to accept a list of words on the command line, and put them in an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

subsequences () {
    local array=("$@")
    local this=${array[0]}
    local tail
    echo "$this"
    [ "${#array[@]}" -eq 1 ] && return
    subsequences "${array[@]:1}" |
    while IFS='' read -r tail; do
        printf '%s && %s\n' "$this" "$tail"
        echo "$tail"
    done
}
 
subsequences "$@"
```

If you saved this as `subsequences` (in a directory in your `PATH`, and `chmod +x subsequences`), you'd run this like

```
subsequences fire water air
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/jfBwTr

The output order is different than in your example; if the order is significant, it should not be hard to refactor this (though then perhaps an iterative solution would be better than a recursive one).

Comment: https://ideone.com/hcdMY5 is an iterative version which produces exactly the expected output.

Comment: shouldn't the expected output include also `fire air` and the empty string? there are eight results from (fire or nothing)(water or nothing)(air or nothing)

Comment: @jhnc By the example in the question, I infer that the OP wants subsequences, not all possible combinations. It won't be hard to edit this to also include an empty result if you genuinely need that too.

Comment: I went by the paragraph of text. Also, the code in the question seems to be a (broken) way to insert `&&` not a way to generate subsequences

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971581/jhnc).

Use `local -n ...` to create variables in a function and pass variable names in calls:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

r () {
    read -rp "Give text: " var
}

m () {
    local -n l_g=$2
    local -n l_v=$3
    if [[ -n "$l_g" ]] ; then
        l_v=" && $1"
    else
        l_v="$1"
        l_g='1'
    fi
}

r
g=
m "$var" g a

r
m "$var" g b

r
m "$var" g c

echo "$a$b$c"
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers my question in a simple manner, but does not really fit the title.

```
#!/bin/bash

r () {
    read -rp "Give text: " var
}

m () {

        if [ -n "$1" ]; then
                echo " && $1"
        else
                echo ''
        fi

}

r
a="$(m "$var")"

r
b="$(m "$var")"

r
c="$(m "$var")"

echo "$a$b$c" | sed 's/ && //1'
```